# AVCHD MTS h264 1080p file with choppy playback in Linux

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-playback, avchd

When I'm trying play video files from my camera:

```
    Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 50.00 (50/1) -> 50.00 (50/1)
Input #0, mpegts, from '00027.MTS':
  Duration: 00:00:38.88, start: 2.884289, bitrate: 16945 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
```

… on my Linux computer (Ubuntu 12.04), I get choppy playback. It's completly unusable... I tried:

- Totem
- VLC
- mplayer

The result is always same issue.

I sent the same video file to a friend who has ubuntu 10.04 to test, and he also has the same issue. He has Windows 7, and confirms that on Windows, the video work well.

I have an Intel® Core™2 CPU 6300 @ 1.86GHz × 2 with GF 9600 GT, with closed NVIDIA drivers. This is not any kind of issue with big files playing slow from an HDD issue. I have an SSD drive!

I spent the last days and nights, trying hundreds of commands for ffmpeg, handbrake, mencoder... 
Any of them won't let me create a file with enough quality.

I downloaded few movies from YouTube in 1080p, and playback worked well without any big pixels and choppiness.

I would like have highest possible quality, I will put following files onto a Blu-ray disk so I don't need to compress them to get a smaller size. I just want smoth playback on my Linux box.

On Windows, the same file is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest giving smplayer a try
although it is a GUI for mplayer which you can run from command line anyway it provides much easier tweaking of settings etc.

Install it and click Options --> Preferences
Under General look to the right, click the Video tab
Although not an expert try changing Output driver to "vdpau"
I believe at least that gives good results for NVidia based cards.

I am running a Radeon on 12.04 vdpau works for me, but also the default xv, gl, gl (fast), gl (fast - ATI cards) seem to work.

It is mainly MTS, M2TS AVCHD videos that gave me dramas but with the above it seems just OK...although still battling to get time remaining showing and therefore any chance to "skip" forward etc, if you know an answer for me on that one holla out :)

Good luck.

Stretch

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I realize I may be late to the game here but looking at your output:

`1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr,`

You can see that your video is 50 FPS. Which means that it's going to be require roughly twice the processing power to decode than the (probably) 25 FPS youtube movies you tried.

### Solution

You can transcode the video to a lower frame rate to make it playable, something like this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -r 25 -preset fast -tune film \
    -profile high10 output.mp4
```

Or you could get a graphics card that supports hardware decoding of H264 such as Nvidia Geforce 8 series or later and use a player that supports [VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) and use a video player that uses it such as a recent mplayer version.